# Select records that appear twice, with a slight difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have quick question on a select I'm trying to do.

Lets assume my Table is as below.

```
ID | Name | Surname | Passed |
1    john   Doe       N
2    John   Doe       Y
3    Marry  Kurn      Y
4    Donald Spec      N
5    Henry  Keller    N
6    Henry  Keller    Y
7    Moe    Miller    Y
8    Jerry  Ken       N
9    Jerry  Ken       C
10   Beth   Spec      Y
```

So I only want to select the people who have 2 records one is passed `N` and the other is Passed `Y` or `C`.

In this case it would be `John Doe`, `Henry Keller` and `Jerry Ken`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Surname
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Name,
    Surname
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Passed IN ('C', 'Y') THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Passed IN ('N') THEN 1 END) > 0;
```